# Are there other sites similar to MSE and MO?

Tags: support

I am very fond of math stack exchange and overflow. But sometimes I don't get answers to the questions I ask. Are there other sites like this? Also, I would like to enhance my problem solving skills so that I can solve my inquires myself. Are there sites for that? I am just a lover of math who has a few questions buzzing in my head.

Comment: Maybe this could be interesting for you: [Useful mathematical fora](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95787/useful-mathematical-fora).

Comment: If you do post a question to more than one site, please remember to link each post to all of the others.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic, because the question is about sites *other than* Math.SE. The topic of meta is Math.SE. The question would be on-topic on the main site, where it is a duplicate of the post pointed out by Martin Sleziak.

Comment: @user147263 i think it's a reasonable question and here are ma ny people who can answer it. when we do meta-logic, then we compare logical systems e.g., so why can't we talk about other platforms when we do meta-stackexchange? :) i think it can stay open

Comment: if you can speak german, matheplanet is one such site! also you can write articles there, which is something this site misses

Comment: shiddd. I am migrating there. Auf Wiedersehen to MSE it seems like @Nico

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Haha :) Bitte gerne